# string to date time conversion

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

I have two fields create date:20151109 and create time:0540 both are String with precision 8 and 4 , now I need to do concatenation  both and convert it to DateTime format in expression transformation . how can I achieve this?

Thanks,
 Kiran

Comment: samik, I tried TO_DATE(CREATION_DATE||CREATION_TIME,'YYYY-MM-DDHH24MISS')  but its throwing error, i need the o/p as 201511090540

Comment: The format string should match the source date format

Comment: i tried either ways its still saying invalid string to converting date

Answer (score 0):

I have executed the below SQL in SQL developer

select to_date('201511090540','yyyymmddHHMI') from dual

to verify if above is working
select to_char(to_date('201511090540','yyyymmddHHMI'),'DD-MON-YY HH:MI') from dual;

Steps in informatica to achieve this

1) concatenate both data and the time using || in the expression , say VAR1

2) Then use to_date('VAR1','yyyymmddHHMI') --> Need to have the port as date time

Try this let me know if it is working, as I have not tested it on informatica

Thanks and Regards,

Raj

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate both the fields using "||" OR operator in a variable port and apply TO_DATE(ConcatenatedField,"YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI") to it.